# Spring Data - Specification Join with hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have problems with a specification, in which I am trying to do a left Join between two classes, that are children of two abstract classes.

I have a Hierarchy like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public abstract class Product {
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_seq", sequenceName = "product_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "product_seq")
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String brand;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Fridge extends Product {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_seq", sequenceName = "product_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "product_seq")
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  private String otherField;
  ...
}
```

In addition, I have other classes like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
public abstract class Offer {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
  private Product product;
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@JsonDeserialize(using = FridgeOfferDeserializer.class)
@Table(name = "offer")
public class FridgeOffer extends Offer {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "offer_gen", sequenceName = "offer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "offer_gen")
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
  private Fridge product;
  ...
}
```

In my specification, I have a code like this:

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<FridgeOffer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

    Join<FridgeOffer, Fridge> join = root.join("product", JoinType.LEFT);
    Path<String> expression = join.get(searchCriteria.getKey());
    ...
}
```

but every time that I perform a request filtering for a child's field, I have the following error:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [otherField] on this ManagedType [com.fishingoffers.main.abstracts.Product]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [otherField] on this ManagedType [com.fishingoffers.main.abstracts.Product]
```

I tried with other_field (the name of the column) but I have the same problem. The most extrange part of the message, is that hibernate seems to be doing the lookup in the Product class, instead of Fridge, that is the one that I choose in the specification. If I try with columns defined in Product, everything is OK. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the problem is, that `FridgeOffer` has two attributes with the same name `product` because the private fields don't overload they hide each other. Not sure how Hibernate or Spring Data handles that nor how they actually should handle it. So the question becomes, what is the purpose of this duplicate definition? Type safety? Overwriting of JPA annotations? For the purpose of this question I'd suggest loosing one of the fields or giving it different names to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution, I changed product for fridge and it works. About your question, this design has the purpose of reuse code since I have several similar microservices that has almost same fields, so I want to define only the specific fields in each one, using inheritance for the common  attributes. In addition I have many services and repositories that will have same behavior, so, it is possible that I should change to some design with Java Generics in order to avoid this messy code.